# Data Table Deferred loading of data. How to pass the "deferLoading" value dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Using Data Table for server side pagination. Here first page of the table has already been preloaded in the HTML.
This can be acieved using Deferred loading of data. Below link has been used to get the details.

[this site](https://floridahalfcentury.org/jQuery/DataTables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

Here deferLoading value is hardcoded, so how can  pass this "deferLoading" value dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "deferLoading": 57
    } );
} );
```

The below code is not working. Is there a way there we can change the deferLoading value later ?

```
function loadInitialData(){
//ajax call to load initial html data
    var totalRecords = //get Value from server;
    table.deferLoading = totalRecords;
    table.fnDraw();
}
```

Below data is returned by the Ajax call

```
[               [0,'2021072701587','08:04:57'],
               [1,'2021072701585','08:03:46'],
               [2,'2021072701585','08:02:44']
]
```

But then from second time, by using using I'm getting the page count error like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the `deferLoading` value via an initial (separate) Ajax call - for example, using jQuery ajax. You can then pass that value to your DataTable upon completion of the initial Ajax call.

So, assuming we have already built our HTML table and populated it with some data:

```
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>5421</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> ... and more initial rows... </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Then we can use a script as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/preload-count"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    initializeTable( data.count );
  });

  function initializeTable(deferDataCount) {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      serverSide: true,
      "deferLoading": deferDataCount,
      ajax: {
        url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/serverside-data",
      },
      "columns": [
        { "title": "ID", "data": "id" },
        { "title": "Name", "data": "name" },
        { "title": "Position", "data": "position" },
        { "title": "Salary", "data": "salary" },
        { "title": "Start Date", "data": "start_date" },
        { "title": "Office", "data": "office" },
        { "title": "Extn.", "data": "extn" }
      ]
    });
  }

} );
```

In the above script, we first call the following URL:

```
url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/preload-count"
```

This returns a simple JSON structure containing the count we want to use in the `deferLoading` option - so, in my case it is this:

```js
{
  "count": 57
}
```

This integer is then passed to my `initializeTable(deferDataCount)` function, where the DataTable is initialized with the count I need to use:

```
"deferLoading": deferDataCount,
```

Now, the next time a user action is performed (paging/filtering/sorting) the DataTable will use its URL to fetch the next page of data:

```
url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/serverside-data"
```

And this URL will return all the required `serverSide` values needed by DataTables, including row data JSON which (in my case) looks like this:

```js
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "salary": "$170,750",
  "start_date": "2011/07/25",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "8422"
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is my full web page, for reference, to show how all the pieces fit together:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>5421</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


  $.ajax({
    url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/preload-count"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    initializeTable( data.count );
  });

  function initializeTable(deferDataCount) {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      serverSide: true,
      "deferLoading": deferDataCount,
      ajax: {
        url: "YOUR_URL_HERE/serverside-data",
      },
      "columns": [
        { "title": "ID", "data": "id" },
        { "title": "Name", "data": "name" },
        { "title": "Position", "data": "position" },
        { "title": "Salary", "data": "salary" },
        { "title": "Start Date", "data": "start_date" },
        { "title": "Office", "data": "office" },
        { "title": "Extn.", "data": "extn" }
      ]
    });
  }

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This not initializing the data table, there is no pagination bar after implementing this way.

Comment: Also, Do I need to Initialize data table in $(document).ready ?

Comment: I added the full web page content to my answer, to see if that helps to clarify my approach (yes, you always need to place your DataTable initialization in a "document ready" function). If that does not help, you can update your question to show your updated approach and any browser console errors you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, that is working, Having another issue, question is updated.

Comment: Glad it is working. Can you create a new question for this new issue?

Comment: created new question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68698956/how-can-i-send-records-total-value-to-data-table