# How can I send records Total value to data table

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

This is the issue

[image: This is the defect, total page Number is NaN]

Initilaizing the data table with defer loading and server side pagination.

```
function intializeTransactionListDatatable(totalCount){
        $('#transactionResult').DataTable({
        searching : false,
        info : false,
        //lengthChange : false,
        serverSide : true,
        processing : true,
        "ajax": {
            type : "POST",                      
            url : $("#context").val() +"/MaintenanceController",
            data : buildSearchData, // create request data
            dataSrc : function(json){
                return processResponse(json)
            }
        },
        pageLength: 10,
        deferLoading:totalCount,
    });
}
```

Process the json response to the required data table format.

```
function  processResponse(json){
    var dataTableData = {};
    dataTableData.draw = 1;
    dataTableData.recordsTotal = 25;
    var dataTableRow = []
    for( var i=0; i < json.length ; i++){ 
        dataTableRow.push([ i, json[i].value, ] );
    }
    dataTableData.data  = dataTableRow;
    return dataTableData.data;
}
```

Only Data is returned. So total number is "NaN".

When i tried to return the entire object dataTableRow error alert is showing json response error in data table.

Comment: You can edit your question to show us the JSON (as text).

Comment: I forgot to mention: the JSON sent from the server to your DataTable needs to contain `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` values, as described [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). See examples [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data).